# How can I disable links for categories but keep showing them on my blog in an Elementor Template?

Tags: plugins, categories, link-category

I have a website with blogs, I am displaying categories on the blog using Elementor but the categories generate its respective link.

[image]

```html
<ul class="elementor-inline-items elementor-icon-list-items elementor-post-info">
                                <li class="elementor-icon-list-item elementor-repeater-item-ba9c996 elementor-inline-item">
                        <a href="https://www.yapsody.com/ticketing/blog/2023/11/03/">
                                            <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
                                <svg aria-hidden="true" class="e-font-icon-svg e-fas-calendar" viewBox="0 0 448 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M12 192h424c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v260c0 26.5-21.5 48-48 48H48c-26.5 0-48-21.5-48-48V204c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12zm436-44v-36c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48h-48V12c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12h-40c-6.6 0-12 5.4-12 12v52H160V12c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12h-40c-6.6 0-12 5.4-12 12v52H48C21.5 64 0 85.5 0 112v36c0 6.6 5.4 12 12 12h424c6.6 0 12-5.4 12-12z"></path></svg>                            </span>
                                    <span class="elementor-icon-list-text elementor-post-info__item elementor-post-info__item--type-date">
                                        November 3, 2023                    </span>
                                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="elementor-icon-list-item elementor-repeater-item-9b73596 elementor-inline-item">
                                        <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
                                <svg aria-hidden="true" class="e-font-icon-svg e-fas-tags" viewBox="0 0 640 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M497.941 225.941L286.059 14.059A48 48 0 0 0 252.118 0H48C21.49 0 0 21.49 0 48v204.118a48 48 0 0 0 14.059 33.941l211.882 211.882c18.744 18.745 49.136 18.746 67.882 0l204.118-204.118c18.745-18.745 18.745-49.137 0-67.882zM112 160c-26.51 0-48-21.49-48-48s21.49-48 48-48 48 21.49 48 48-21.49 48-48 48zm513.941 133.823L421.823 497.941c-18.745 18.745-49.137 18.745-67.882 0l-.36-.36L527.64 323.522c16.999-16.999 26.36-39.6 26.36-63.64s-9.362-46.641-26.36-63.64L331.397 0h48.721a48 48 0 0 1 33.941 14.059l211.882 211.882c18.745 18.745 18.745 49.137 0 67.882z"></path></svg>                          </span>
                                    <span class="elementor-icon-list-text elementor-post-info__item elementor-post-info__item--type-terms">
                                        <span class="elementor-post-info__terms-list">
                <span class="elementor-post-info__terms-list-item">Event Marketing</span>, <span class="elementor-post-info__terms-list-item">Event Strategies</span>               </span>
                    </span>
                                </li>
                </ul>
```

I have disabled the links from being clicked by making `pointer-events: none;`, but that doesn't stop the link from being generated (eg. https://www.yapsody.com/ticketing/blog/devise-the-perfect-event-marketing-strategy-for-your-upcoming-event/ )

Is there a way I can display the categories but stop wordpress from generating link for these categories

Comment: that link leads to a 404, but I see the categories on another post. Unfortunately those pages are not output the normal way and were built using the Elementor plugin, you need Elementor help not general WordPress help, and should ask this in an Elementor community if you don't have their support